# storing the entire strings starting with a "." in a file

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to find all the strings in a file that start with a "." in MATLAB. I have the following code,

```
data_files = 's.txt';
 C = textread(data_files, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
filetext = fileread(data_files);
expr='\.' ;
fileread_info = regexp(filetext, expr, 'match');
fid = fopen('size.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n',fileread_info{:});
```

intput:

```
.hello world
hello there
.can i help you
no
```

output is :

```
.
.
```

Instead of

```
.hello world
.can i help you
```

How can you extract the entire string that starts with a "." instead of just writing "." into the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying regex as follows

```
expr = '^\s*\..*$' ;
```

`.*` is required to match all the contents of a line starting with `.`

Comment: It now reads all the lines having a "." instead of the lines starting with a "."

Comment: @LearnerRealTimeControlSystem please try now.

Comment: i get error "??? expr = expr = '^\s*\..*$' ;
                |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment."

Comment: you wrote `expr = expr = '^\s*\..*$' ;` ?? Why there is an extra `expr =` ? I don't know what's going wrong at your end. For me it worked fine.